# Fake missing layout attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, lint

I have a separator view in a LinearLayout like this:

```
<View style="@style/Separator" />
```

Android Studio 4.1.3 Lint (through Analyze>Inspect Code...) tells me for this line:

```
The required layout_width and layout_height attributes are missing
```

Yet, the style/Separator is included in a library that I use, through the library file `res/values/style.xml` whose content is:

```
....
<style name="Separator">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#007788</item>
</style>
```

As you see, the `layout_width` and `layout_height` are there, and are actually read and respected by Android.

What is going on, and how can I fix this annoying lint (obviously without changing the inspection settings or suppressing the lint)?

**EDIT:** This only happens when I use the `View` from the library. So if the styles file is local to the app, no lint error is issued.

Comment: Would suppressing the lint warning locally just for this View be an option?

Comment: @laalto: Too troublesome. I have 27 views with this warning, and I keep changing the thing al the time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` in the `View` as a parameter.
The reason is:
The layout values are not reachable in your `style.xml`, but in your `Layout` (as the name implies.)

It should look like that in your `Layout`:

```
<View style="@style/Separator"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="w1dp" />
```

and in your `styles.xml`:

```
....
<style name="Separator">
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#007788</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of styles not to have to write the style in the view, and to be sure that all look the same? Your solution goes against this, IMHO.

Comment: Yes of course. You are right, but this issue isn't fixed for years and when it will be there after some updates again. This is a well known issue for many years. I just try to help what is possible at the moment. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37138580

Comment: Oh boy... I see. Funny thing is that it works perfectly if the style is not in the library, but in the app itself. Anyway.... thanks!

Comment: Yeah. Like a menu. Some values are only limited reachable. For instants the res/values/menu is only for menu and can't be reached for layouts. (like res/values/styles). Have nice day of coding buddy!

Comment: Interesting, and useful information. So I duplicated the parts of the styles.xml needed, and the errors are gone. Thanks a lot for your help, and all the best! ;)